# Pygame window is not responding and then it displays an error

Tags: pygame, python-3.7

```
import pygame
#initialize the screen
pygame.init()

#create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

#tile and icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
            running = False
```

my pygame window does not respond and then it displays the error 'int object is not callable'.i use the community version of visual studio 2019.

Comment: if event.type == pygame.QUIT: should do it. It's not a method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to counter the error given by your program, you need to use pygame.QUIT, not pygame.QUIT() as each event type is given a number and pygame.QUIT is set to the number which is returned when you click on the cross.

For your second problem, you just need to add pygame.display.flip() or pygame.display.update(), as this is needed to update the screen. They're basically equivalent, but update can take in a rectangle as a parameter as well, allowing you to only update part of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
root = pygame.init()
```

Most importantly, you forgot to write `root.mainloop()` at the end of the program.
That's the main reason why your window is not responding.